# If the cardinality of $B(X)$, the space of operators on $X$, is continuum, must $X$ be separable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Does there exits any non-separable Banach space $X$ such that the size (cardinal number) of $B(X)$, bdd linear operators on $X$, is just of the continuum?

Comment: What is $B(X)$?

Comment: @TarasBanakh: Edited.

Comment: I hope that a counterexample can be found in papers of Koszmider, for example, in  https://www.impan.pl/~koszmider/badania/fewsur2.pdf or https://link.springer.com/article/10.5052%2FRACSAM.2010.19

Comment: @TarasBanakh, the problem with spaces $K$ such that every operator on $C(K)$ is of the form $gI+W$ where $g\in C(K)$ and $W$ weakly compact, is that there is no clear way how to count weakly compact operators on them.

Comment: @TomekKania The number of weakly compact operators is the number of weakly compact sets times the number of continuous operators mapping the unit ball to a given weakly compact set. The number of weakly compact sets should not exceed $|X^*|^\omega$ and if all weakly compact sets are metrizable (in the weak topology), then the number of continuous operators mapping the unit ball to a given weakly compact set also should not exceed $|X^*|^\omega$. So, for a Banach space $X$ with ``small'' weakly compact sets, the number of weakly compact operators should not exceed $|X^*|^\omega$. Right?

Comment: I think it okay. Then this space will be ZFC counterexample

https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/studia-mathematica/all/241/3/92306/a-non-separable-uniformly-convex-banach-space-on-which-there-are-few-operators

Comment: The exists eveb simpler ZFC-example -- the Banach space $C(K)$ over the Alexandroff two-arrows space $K$, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of a non-separable Banach space $X$ with $|B(X)|=\mathfrak c$ is  any non-separable Banach space $X$ whose dual $X^*$ is $w^*$-separable and has cardinality $|X^*|=\mathfrak c$.

This follows from the observation that the map $B(X)\to B(X^*)$, $T\mapsto T^*$, is injective and hence for a countable $w^*$-dense set $D$ in $X^*$ we have  $$|B(X)|\le |B(X^*)|\le |(X^*)^{D}|=|X^*|^\omega=\mathfrak c^\omega=\mathfrak c.$$

A ZFC-example of a non-separable Banach space $X$ whose dual space $X^*$ is $w^*$-separable and has cardinality $|X^*|=\mathfrak c$ is the Banach space $X=C(K)$ of continuous functions on the [Alexandroff two-arrow space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_interval) $K$.

The $w^*$-separability of the dual space $X^*$ was proved by Corson, see Theorem 12.43 in [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Analysis-Infinite-Dimensional-Geometry-Mathematics/dp/1441929126/ref=sr_1_2/257-8911836-5630525?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1528542703&sr=1-2). The equality $|X^*|=\mathfrak c$ can be seen analyzing the structure of (probability) measures on the compact space $K$.

Answer (score 10):

Assume Martin's axiom and the negation of CH. Then $2^{\omega_1}=\mathfrak c$. Let $X=\ell_2(\omega_1)$. Every operator on $X$ is determined by its values on a dense set of cardinality $\omega_1$, hence there are at most $$|\ell_2(\omega_1)|^{\omega_1} = (\omega_1^\omega)^{\omega_1}\leqslant (2^\omega)^{\omega_1}=2^{\omega_1}=\mathfrak c$$ operators on $X$. Consequently, $|B(\ell_2(\omega_1))|=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Nice argument. What about under continuum hypothesis?